# Is it safe to sign into subscription services on a holiday smart tv

Tags: appletv

I am renting a cottage for a week holiday and it has a smart tv. That is tempting to watch Foundation etc on Apple TV rather than my tablet screen.

However I am concerned that there could be residual info for next person to use the credentials

If I do this how can I ensure clean exit?

Comment: Logout should remove your credentials but may leave your AppleID visible for the next guest (depends on the actual SmartTV model). Is resetting the TV an option?

Comment: It looks like a factory reset is available. Thanks to Andy for corrections to my fat finger typos. I will have a go to watch latest Foundation episode

Comment: Every hotel smart TV I've ever used promises to clean all authentication information when you check out.

Comment: Do you have an apple laptop / iDevice with you - if so can you not screenshare from the laptop with the TV [no login required then ??]